# How to send data from ServerSocket to Socket?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

After asking so many question about android socket programming and getting valuable answers from stackoverflow's members i could do a well working program using sockets to connect two device over wifi.
Thanks to all.
But still i am having some problem..

i have done the program in which
   ** Data can be sent from client and received at serverSocket**
But still i am not getting how to **Send data from server which can be received at client**

Code for Server Socket

```
private OnClickListener bt_sendListner = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String msg=et_msg.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Msg", msg);
        Thread threadsendmsg = new Thread(new Threadsendmsg(msg));
        threadsendmsg.start();

    }
};



public class Threadsendmsg implements Runnable{

    String msg;

    public Threadsendmsg(String msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      this.msg=msg;


    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try {

             Looper.prepare();
                Log.d("Msg", "Inside the thread");


             //connected = true; 
                while (true) {
                    try {

                        Log.d("Msg", "Msg to be sent");

                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(serverSocket.accept().getOutputStream())), true);
                            // where you issue the commands
                            out.println("Client: "+msg);
                            Log.d("Msg", "Msg sent"+out.toString());

                            break;
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    tv_chatbox.setText("S: Error= "+ e.getMessage());
                             Log.d("Msg", e.getMessage());   
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
              //  socket.close();
              //  console.append("\nC: Closed.");
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        tv_chatbox.setText("S: Error= "+ e.getMessage());
                                 Log.d("Msg", e.getMessage());


                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //      console.append("\nC: Error= "+ e.getMessage());

                    }
                });

           //   connected = false;
            }



    }




}



public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() { 
        try {
            Looper.prepare();
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString()
                                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                serverStatus.append("\n"+serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());

                    }
                });



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString()
                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                serverStatus.append("\n"+serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                        }
                     });

                    try { 
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);

                          final  String myline=new String(line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    tv_chatbox.setText("Client said:="+myline);

                                    // do whatever you want to the front end
                                    // this is where you can be creative
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error"+e.getMessage());

                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**There is no method as ServerSocket.getOutputStream() in ServerSocket class.**Which i have used client socket...

Comment: What does your Threadsendmsg class do? Is it client?

Comment: It sends the msg to server.i tried same  for server socket class to send msg to client but it didnt work...

Comment: kindly put the client code also ,I have searched a lot but Invain, I have spent one whole week on it but can't implement it still.

Comment: `ServerSockets` cannot send or receive data. The question is meaningless.

Comment: @EJP - the question is not meaningless, it simply results from a misunderstanding of the difference between a *ServerSocket* and the *server-side* socket resulting from accepting a connection.  It would be more productive to contribute an explanation of that than to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both client and server use the same class Socket. But client creates his socket instance manually and connects to server. Server on the other hand listens at some port and when client connects, socket for server is created and returned from method accept(). 
In your code you can use

```
client.getOutputStream();
```